# Button click handler is not being called

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Here's my code:

```
<input type="button" id="btn"  value="Click" />

<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        var Idtype = $("#dropdownlist").val();
        var valuetype = $('#dropdownlist option:selected').text();
        $.post("/Role/displayvalue", { Id: $('#dropdownlist').val(), value: $('#dropdownlist option:selected').text() }, function (data) {
            $("#dropdownlist").html(data)
        })
    });
});

</script>
```

Here's the `displayvalue` function:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult displayvalue(int Id, string value, [DataSourceRequest]  DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
```

When I click the button, the `displayvalue()` function is not being called when the button is clicked. What is causing this?

Comment: This works fine as a jsfiddle (i.e. it makes a call to /Role/displayRolevalue which doesn't exist on that server). See http://jsfiddle.net/grantgibson/64cYs/. Check your browsers javascript console to see what it's trying to do - this might be an ASP question rather than HTML/Javascript.

Comment: I would rearrange the order you have your parameters in. I would have `[DataSourceRequest]  DataSourceRequest request` be the first parameter listed.

Answer (score 0):

displayRolevalue return view , no data in JSON or XML format!!!!!
you can use WebApi.

see [MVC using Web API and JQuery to GET or POST Data](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/678138/MVC-using-Web-API-and-JQuery-to-GET-or-POST-Data)

Comment: Or you can check what format was requested and return in an appropriate format.

Comment: No If u want , u can return view from action from controller. its not mandatory to return json data